# google sheets query returning returning a row with empty cell even though condition checks for null

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am working on a workflow process in the sheet below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MS-UydJ9EJ_jOrSwSt1o4Lh6ekGQxpsprFz2RAq6CdI/edit?usp=sharing

I am facing an odd issue. In the DataStudio sheet i have a query which checks the actual and planned columns in the FMS sheet and should not return any results where the planned column is null. In the current sheet it is returning one row where the planned column is blank.
To check this I queried the specific range in FMS in Sheet35 with the query in cell G1

```
=query({FMS!B8:B,FMS!U8:V},"select * where Col2 is not null")
```

this is returning a row where Col2 is blank and should not pass the condition is not null. I dont know
if I am missing something very fundamental here as I even as a check tried to set the cell to IFERROR(0/0) which should return a blank and that still shows in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({FMS!B8:B, FMS!U8:V}, "where Col2 is not null", 0)
```